# Where can I find a free web server to host a .xap file?

Tags: silverlight-3.0

I can't use the silverlight free hosting because I can't use iframes to embed my video for my site. I can't use .html either.

I just need a place to host the file, for free. No FTP either.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to host the file for free.

[000webhost](http://www.000webhost.com/) should do the trick.

PS: Its also as FTP, PHP Mysql.

Comment: It's forcing my .xap file to open as a .zip file

Do you know of a workaround?

Comment: Sounds like the MIME type is not mapped correctly. You could try asking the host to change it. As a workaround I would try renaming the .xap file to .zip, then also changing the file name in the html.

Comment: "I'm sorry but Silverlight applications are not supported." They told me :(

Comment: Never used it, but try Google Sites